# css folder not found in git repository after push all code

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I have one project, inside project `public folder` have css and other library folder have css folder like below

```
Public\
  \css
  \js
  \datepicker
    \css
    \js
```

but when i push all code to git repository css folder cant be push and git repository have no css folder  inside any folder. like below

```
public\
  \js
  \datepicker
    \js
```

no css folder found in git repository. i have also remove `.gitignore` file but cant resolve this issue.

i used below command for git

```
git add .
git commit -m 'comment'
git push -u origin development //development is my child branch of master
```

Comment: what you get from `git status` right now? Do you have something in your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: Is that folder empty? If not, have you tried adding those files individually?

Comment: no any updated files in `git status`

Answer (score 1):

If the folder is empty (there's no file inside) the folder will not be pushed to remote.

Also, `git add .` only adds files in the current folder and its sub-folders. To be sure that you are adding all files, use instead `git add -A`